# Showing Date in different format in javascript datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, datepicker

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to make a date-picker widget, I have the selected date in mm/dd/yy format,how can I get the date as "Thu(Day),25th July(Date,month) ,2013" kind of format and also how to set the input value to the current date.Here's my fiddle,
  http://jsbin.com/idowik/3/
  http://jsbin.com/idowik/3/edit
There are so much warnings , please bear with me and please open the output in new tab. Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs about the Date Object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.
Everything you need is described there.

Have a look at the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="dateInput" type="text"></input>
        <button id="convertButton">Convert to string</button>
        <a id="dateString"></a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
            var button = document.getElementById("convertButton");
            var dateString = document.getElementById("dateString");
            var date;
            button.onclick = function() {
                var year = 2000+ parseInt(dateInput.value.split("/")[2]);
                var month = dateInput.value.split("/")[0];
                var day = dateInput.value.split("/")[1];

                date = new Date(year, month, day);

                dateString.innerHTML = date.toDateString();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This html page does exactly what you want.

Comment: what did you write in the input box? Try something like 11/12/13 or 06/23/13